# How to create an emmet or constructive snippet in vs-code for dart

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, emmet, vscode-snippets

I guess the title is pretty obvious, what i want is to define a snippet which should convert something simillar to:

```dart
textcontrollers*4
```

to

```dart
final TextEditingController $1 = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController $2 = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController $3 = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController $4 = TextEditingController();
```

or constructive like:

```dart
list_of_textcontrollers
```

to

```dart
final TextEditingController $ = TextEditingController();//and if i press enter it should make a new line with same snippet
final TextEditingController $ = TextEditingController();
```

Honestly am new to making extensions and snippets in vs-code(or at all) but i didn't have any luck in googling what i want, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First define a folder for emmet extensions in `settings.json` (Global or Workspace)

A good location is the `.vscode` directory of the Workspace/Project

```
"emmet.extensionsPath": "/c:/Projects/CoolStuff/.vscode"
```

On Windows you need to use this format to specify the path.

In this folder create a file `snippets.json`

```
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "tec": "{final TextEditingController ${1:name} = TextEditingController();}"
    }
  }
}
```

**Restart VSC** otherwise the changes to `snippets.json` are not read by emmet.

Use short names for the snippet because if you want to use the `*4` syntax you have to type the fullname.

Now you can type `tec*4` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and with <kbd>Tab</kbd> fill in the names.

If you remove the placeholder `:name` you get tab stops but not one at the end.

---

Use **Selection** | **Copy Line Down** for the other use case.

Comment: @OverLoadedBurden https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types